# Short Surveys on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, survey, insights

I'm Katrina, a member of the comms and marketing team at Stack Overflow.

---

You may notice short surveys popping up on Stack Overflow. This is part of #StackOverflowKnows, an ongoing initiative showcasing insights on hot topics and industry trends. The first one is a survey on blockchain, which takes less than 2 minutes to complete.

**Why are we doing this?**

These short surveys allow us to gather insights from the community on granular developer trends and topics that signal how technology is evolving and shifting throughout the year. Unlike the Developer Survey, we will be asking for perspectives on a specific topic or trend. These short surveys take less than 2 minutes to complete.

**What types of questions are you asking?**

We’re asking some basic background questions to ensure we’re getting a representative sample of the community. After that, there are just a few multiple choice questions pertaining to your personal opinion or experience relating to a certain topic or technology.

**How can I take the survey?**

If you’re interested in participating in these surveys, we promote them through ads and on our social channels. Like our annual Developer Survey, anyone can participate. It's not limited to just logged in users.

**Are responses anonymous?**

All responses are completely anonymous. No PII is collected. No data is tied to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange user account information. No information is passed to any marketing database. We don’t sell the data. It’s purely intended for research purposes.

**Will we be publicly sharing these results?**

Yes! We will be analyzing results and sharing them on the blog and through social channels. Here are links to survey recaps we've published thus far:

- [What developers think about blockchain](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/07/most-developers-believe-blockchain-technology-is-a-game-changer-3/)
- [Cloud developer trends](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/09/02/pandemic-lockdowns-accelerated-cloud-migration-by-three-to-four-years/)
- [What do developers consider when evaluating current and future jobs](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/07/new-data-what-developers-look-for-in-future-job-opportunities/)
- [Top movies and coding music according to developers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/03/24/new-data-top-movies-and-coding-music-according-to-developers/)

**Stay Tuned**

More peer insights coming to [#StackOverflowKnows](https://stackoverflow.blog/stackoverflowknows/). Keep an eye out for surveys if you’re interested in participating.

Comment: What is the intended use of these survey results?

Comment: So will we get a badge for completion or not?

Comment: *Do you describe yourself as Hispanic or Latino/a/x?* What kind of a question is this and how is it related to blockchain?

Comment: Wait - just three questions? "*Is it a hype, did you join the hype, will you join the hype?*" That's not asking for expertise.

Comment: @oguzismail race is an american obsession these days

Comment: From my point of view, Questions are not related to **programming**.

Comment: A great part about Stack Overflow is keeping the site about technical problems and leaving out politics, trends, social media, and demographics. Let's not social-media-tize SO.

Comment: Maybe developers won't love surveys like that. I think that one survey in one single year (Stack Overflow 2021 Dev Survey) is **enough** which is related to **programming** as well.

Comment: I can understand people feel that race/heritage really has no place in programming, because it doesn't. It doesn't have a place anywhere, except maybe medicine and genetics. The problem is that people *are* being judged by race/heritage, and as far as I understand, the analysis of the survey can try to correlated race, age and/or gender with satisfaction or dissatisfaction of the various elements in the initial part of the survey. Note that no one is forced to take the survey, and even if they do, they can just not answer the questions about race, age, gender..

Comment: @Scratte - I think the harsh reception the survey gets is because of the misrepresentation of its content in the announcement post. "signal how technology is evolving and shifting throughout the year" does sound to me like a technical survey, whereas in the actual survey the followups are basically 1. Hype or not; 2. Did you use it? 3. Which one? Not as bad as I imagined it to be judging from the responses, though.

Comment: Apparently we didn't learn our lesson [the last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper).  [See also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401807/stack-overflow-survey-youre-still-spending-too-much-time-focusing-on-demograph).

Comment: @Scratte yes, so much of our world is now boiled down to race, but SO was one place where, imo, race, gender, how you look, none of that matters. Here you can totally shed your biological self and focus only on getting and giving technical help to people. If the question is good, who cares who the person asking is, people will try to answer because we care about being helpful and contributing to the library of technical knowledge the community has built here.

Comment: @wxz unless, of course, you want to in any way participate in improving the system, because the only method of feedback they act on is a result of "random" surveys that ask your race/gender.

Comment: "Game changer" or "All hype" - is there no place for nuance? After the irrelevant questions, this one made me close the tab.

Comment: @RobertHarvey they keep pushing this mess down our throats because they believe it's safe for them to do. The only way to have it stop is probably to push back in a way that will harm marketing geniuses inventing stuff like that. For example, [vote for Stack Overflow competitors in this year’s Webby Awards](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/29/vote-for-stack-overflow-in-this-years-webby-awards/)

Answer (score 29):

What's the point of this survey? Why are you doing racial profiling? What does it mean to be "Hispanic or Latino". **What does it have to do with blockchain or programming at all?**

It just seems to me like you are trying to gather personal information on users and "the blockchain question" is just an excuse to gather sensitive information.

When creating surveys please remember that not everyone comes from a racist country. I fail to see what race or ethnic prejudice has to do with technology. I don't understand what kind of information you could possibly gain from such a survey. I am totally disappointed.

Comment: If only "white" people take the survey, and then we report it as how everyone thinks, we've done something bad. Similarly, if only men take it and we make it seem line everyone feels that way - that's bad. It's understandable to want to protect your privacy but we want to sample responses across demographics so that we know we're not only representing a single segment of the population of people when we share the results of the survey.

Comment: @Catija That sounds backwards. Isn't it easier to say, like, *among those who took the survey, 30% think blockchain technology is a hype*, or anything to that effect? Besides you guys already do that with the annual developer survey. See [Rust being the "the most loved programming language" is misleading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398178/rust-being-the-the-most-loved-programming-language-is-misleading)

Comment: But no one knows who took the survey then, @oguzismail  ? - it becomes somewhat useless. It could represent all women or all people who are actually dogs because it's the internet... it's more useful to be able to say, "we surveyed a diverse group of 1000 people and this is how they responded to our questions." I'm not aware of whether we plan to break responses down by segments but it'd be interesting to see -"[subgroup] who responded think ____." Sometimes inequality exacerbates answers in one direction or the other.

Comment: Why can't you just present the survey to anyone who wants to take it and don't look at their race at all?

Comment: Even if only "blue" people took the survey I would have no problem with the results. After all, they are my brothers. [People is people.](https://i.imgflip.com/59dwew.jpg)

Comment: This kind of racist approach should have no place on Stack Overflow. It doesn't matter what color a person is. If they can take the survey, their response counts. You can't be so racist to say that if people of only single color take the survey it is invalid. Person's color doesn't matter. Don't make it weird

Comment: @Catija Nah, I don't like that idea at all. I don't think you should be asking us what color we are or what we have in our pants. I won't take any of these surveys, thanks for the reply.

Comment: "not everyone comes from a racist country" - I dunno, I don't think SO gets a lot of traffic from Doesntexistia...

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more than once. I'm sick and tired of them continuing this BS.

Comment: Gotta know the demographics so they can use weights to get the %'s they want, rather than what represents the community.

Answer (score 22):

When I opened the survey, the first question I was asked was what age range I fell within. I answered (between 20 and 24), and immediately I was thanked for responding to the survey and I was surprised as I had apparently reached the end.

Is this intentional? Does that age group represent an audience you're not interested in surveying further?

Comment: It's a well known fact that humans under 30 are mostly hormone-driven machines, so it makes sense to exclude them from surveys. Once you get older you'll understand. /s

Comment: I was the only one who entered my age as 65? Oh well... my age is not related to programming so I decided to lie about it. In fact I argue that no personal characteristics are relevant to this survey at all.

Comment: All the ages before 35 and up don't work. I don't understand why they don't just say explicitly that they're looking for older people to answer it instead of misrepresenting the purpose behind the survey

Comment: @10R Now you've confirmed your age is _not_ 65...

Answer (score 13):

Your country list, which includes "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", is [at least two years out of date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macedonia_naming_dispute). I didn't check for further errors.

Comment: It is now apparently *North Macedonia*.

Comment: I didn't check the list, but there is also Czechia (often confused with [Chechnya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chechnya)) vs. [Czech Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czech_Republic). I *think* both names are valid, but Czechia is *preferred* over Czech Republic (that is, some will get emotional if Czechia is not used).

Comment: @PeterMortensen "Czech Republic" is the proper name. The other thing is a short version, barely used until about 5 years ago.

Comment: @PeterMortensen The Greeks were so upset about Macedonia being called Macedonia that they made them change it to something that still had Macedonia in it.

Comment: @TylerH it's more complex than that. The main point of contention was that Macedonia is not a separate country. Tacking "North" makes it sound like there is a south part of it (which...there geographically is - there is historically an *area* called Macedonia and the country is situated in the northern part of). However, there isn't a South Macedonia country. To the South is Greece. So, it's a bit like the USA forcing Mexico to be called "Souther United States of America". It gives an indirect claim on the country.

Comment: @VLAZ Not sure I follow. Greece doesn't want to own the country now known as North Macedonia (OK, well, sure maybe they want to own their neighbor... who doesn't want more land? Bir Tawil notwithstanding). They want to own the "association with Greece" that the name "Macedonia" carries with it in peoples' minds. Counter to your argument, it would be like if "Texas" were renamed to the state of "Mexico"... Mexico the *country* would obviously not like that very much, and lobby to get the state to change its name to something else.

Comment: @VLAZ In this case, it mattered very much because Greece was blocking The Republic of Macedonia's entrance to NATO due to disputes over the name. If Greece really wanted sovereignty over the Republic of Macedonia, they wouldn't have rescinded their NATO veto as soon as the Republic of Macedonia changed its name to North Macedonia. In fact I think Greece was the *first* to endorse NM's entrance to NATO after the name change. Personally I don't see it as a big deal or difference, between "The Republic of Macedonia" and "North Macedonia"...

Comment: @AakashM It's weird, there was never a country named "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia". It was the Socialist Federal Republic of Yugoslavia until 1991, and then it was simply "Macedonia" until 2019. Maybe there's someone of Greek nationality on Stack Overflow's board? :-P

Answer (score 8):

> What hot topic or industry trend would you like to see us make a short 2-4 question survey about?

Uh... none. Has this turned into a social media site where we need to follow the new trends in the programming industry?

Maybe I'm just overthinking it, but what use does this actually provide to Stack Overflow? We just help programmers out. So then what does making a survey about a hot topic help with?

I understand if you wish to see which technologies are becoming more popular, but that data IMO should be collected in a different way than #StackOverflowKnows.

---

I can also fill the survey multiple times from an icognito window (because there is no IP check). Just tried filling out it again and it actually let me submit it. (I didn't do anything after that though; I don't want to cause harm!)