# "How are we doing? Take our short survey.", oh yeah that was very short with only 1 question

Tags: bug, survey

So I clicked on the survey link and hit the "I am under the age of 18" and hit Next and it redirected me to the home page of Stack Overflow saying "Thank you for taking our survey".

I can't believe we live in a future where they can work out how much we like Stack Overflow just by the click of one question.

Anyways, maybe you guys might wanna fix the survey because it might be broken...

Comment: BTW, this has already been [brought up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407610/short-surveys-on-stack-overflow/407624#407624) on the original post announcing the survey.

Comment: Most of the survey questions are about liquor and wine. Users under 18 (or even 21) can't legally drink in many jurisdictions, so exposing them to the questionnaire would not be fair. Come back in a couple of years and we'll let you on in all the fun.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact, though, that if it's the case, there should be a warning that users under a certain age simply can't take part in the survey (maybe there is one, but I never took part in any). For a developer, the lack of feedback *should* seem like a bug, so I think the OP's question is valid (albeit brought up before).

Comment: @yivi Please tell me you're joking (I'm noticing no "/s" there...).

Comment: How do you have a SE account of you're under 18? Doesn't stackexchange required you to be 18 when creating an account? Unless you weren't serious when clicking that button

Comment: @MendelG - one can have an SE account if they are at least 13 years old (see [ToS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age)), 16 in EU. But sometimes I feel like their psyche would be safer if SE was equated to adult content :)

Comment: My understanding is that we can't (ethically? legally?) collect survey answers from people under the age of 18. I'm not perfectly clear on why, we just don't - and that's what happened.

Comment: It's very common for surveys to begin with screening questions that determine whether the responder fits into the categories that the researchers want to survey.  Terminating the survey early for responders who do not qualify saves time and energy for everyone involved.

Comment: @Catija But if someone lies and says that they are 18 or older, you are still collecting survey answers from people under the age of 18. And I think in most countries you can't hold them juridically responsible for lying... because they are under 18. "Mouse clicks" in general is a very poor way to verify someone's identity.

Comment: @Lundin If someone lies, we can't be held accountable for collecting their answers. We either screen them out to the best of our ability or we don't have surveys at all and we'd rather not eschew the survey entirely because of a handful of people who will think, "maybe I should lie about my age just so I can take this survey...".

Comment: @Catija Using the same flawed logic it is then also fine to give minors alcohol just as long as they lie to you about their age. At least in the civilized world, you can't give that argument in court. Or alternatively, there _is_ no juridical reason why you can't collect results from minors, but...?

Comment: @Lundin - unless you want to ask for an ID for registering on a website, the analogy is not applicable, I am afraid. When an establishment sells alcohol, it has ways of verifying the identity of the customer (and they do), while a website does not have that luxury. SO I agree with Catija here - it is either no surveying or providing reasonable measures of protections (i.e. assuming people answer about their age honestly). And if they were to require an ID to take the survey, they would be collecting PII of an underage if they tried to verify the data supplied.